# Force HTTP (NOT HTTPS) In Blogger

Tags: php, html, http, https, blogger

It will seem strange.
but I want to "force" my blogger blog to always load http.

Some time ago I created my blog in blogger, everything works fine, but a few months ago I started working with iframe elements of websites that do not have SSL-HTTPS, then conflicts with my blog are generated, such as the content that should be displayed within the iframe is not showing, or sometimes showing, but it doesn't work well.

Is there any way to force http on blogger?

(The websites that I make iframe are not my property and i'm using a free blogger domain ".blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to do this through their website: [source](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6284029?hl=en)

Comment: Nope, that article shows how to activate it. But i want to disable it, or force redirect from HTTPS to HTTP